# How to change colors in image with python pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How to change a black and white colors with hex in this image? Using a python pillow.

[image: jjc]

**EDIT:**

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open("TbnlF.png")

width = img.size[0] 
height = img.size[1] 
for i in range(0,width):
    for j in range(0,height):
        data = img.getpixel((i,j))
        if (data[0]==0 and data[1]==0 and data[2]==0):
            img.putpixel((i,j),(255, 255, 0))
        if (data[0]==255 and data[1]==255 and data[2]==255):
            img.putpixel((i,j),(255, 0, 0))
img.save("changed.png")
```

I know how to add a RGB code, but how I add HEX code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImageColor.getrgb(color)` which returns a rgb triple - where *color* can be a string f.x. *#ffffff*.

Comment: Will it work when I import a list of hex codes?